# Swift closure type conversion

Tags: swift, closures

I define a protocol `MessageProtocol`, and class `MessageA`, `MessageB` adopt the protocol.

I want to conver closures like `(MessageA) -> Void` to `(MessageProtocol) -> Void`.

There is code, **solution 1** and **2** can not work well.

```
protocol MessageProtocol {
    func doSomething()
    static func parserFromData() -> MessageProtocol
}

class MessageA: MessageProtocol {
    func doSomething() {
        print("this is A class")
    }

    func functionInA() {
        print("funciton in A")
    }

    static func parserFromData() -> MessageProtocol {
        return MessageA()
    }
}

class MessageB: MessageProtocol {
    func doSomething() {
        print("this is B class")
    }

    func functionInB() {
        print("funciton in b")
    }

    static func parserFromData() -> MessageProtocol {
        return MessageB()
    }
}

// private function .network callback
func callback(type: MessageProtocol.Type, handler: (MessageProtocol?) -> Void) -> Void {
    let obj = type.parserFromData()
    handler(obj)
}

// public function
func response<T: MessageProtocol>(type: T.Type, handler: (T?) -> Void) -> Void {

    // solution 1. compile error
//    let handler: (ABProtocol) -> Void = handler     // compile error
//    callback(type, handler: handler)

    // solution 2. runtime error
//    let handler = handler as! (ABProtocol) -> Void  // runtime error
//    callback(type, handler: handler)

    // solution 3. now i use
    callback(type) { obj in
        handler(obj as? T)
    }
}

response(MessageA.self) { a in
    guard let a = a else {
        return
    }
    a.doSomething()
    a.functionInA()
}

response(MessageB.self) { b in
    guard let b = b else {
        return
    }
    b.doSomething()
    b.functionInB()
}
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're actually trying to do, and why the working solution doesn't work for you.  Seems like this might be an XY Problem based on the complete non-straightfowardness of the issue.

Comment: my question is `MessageA` can conver as `MessageProtocol`, but why conver `(MessageA) -> Void` as `(MessageProtocol) -> Void` will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given some protocol and concrete classes implementing that protocol, you will not be able to upcast a closure's argument from the class to the protocol.

To be clear, given this hierarchy of protocols and classes:

```
protocol FooProtocol {}

class FirstClass: FooProtocol {}
class SecondClass: FooProtocol {}
```

We will never be able to cast this closure:

```
var firstClosure: (FirstClass) -> Void
```

up to this closure:

```
var fooClosure = firstClosure as (FirstClass) -> Void
```

Despite the fact that the compiler would be perfectly happy letting us cast variables of the class itself.  For example:

```
let first: FirstClass = FirstClass()
let foo = first as FooProtocol
```

It doesn't even need to be an `as?` or `as!`.  The compiler knows that `FirstClass` implements the protocol and this will always pass.

The problem with closures is we're not just casting the argument--we're trying to cast the whole closure.

This example should identify *why* the compiler will complain about the cast:

```
protocol DoThingProtocol {
    func doThing()
}

class FooClass: DoThingProtocol {
    var shouldDoThing = false
    func doThing() {
        print("Foo did the thing")
    }
}

class BarClass: DoThingProtocol {
    func doThing() {
        print("Bar did the thing")
    }
}
```

Now, let's suppose we create a closure taking a `FooClass`:

```
let fooClosure: (FooClass) -> Void = { thing in 
    if thing.shouldDoThing {
        thing.doThing()
    }
}
```

The closure is defined as taking a `FooClass` and this concrete closure treats the argument as a `FooClass` instance--it accesses the `shouldDoThing` property of `FooClass` which is not defined on `BarClass`, despite the fact that `BarClass` also implements the `DoThingProtocol`.

Because the closure is going to treat the passed in argument as a `FooClass` and potentially access parts of the argument that are only implements in `FooClass` and not anything that `FooClass` inherits from, you can only pass `FooClass` and its descendants in to the closure.  You can not pass in anything further up the chain, or siblings.

And to be clear, this isn't limited to protocols.  If `DoThingProtocol` where instead `DoThingClass` and a class instance which `FooClass` & `BarClass` inherited from, we'd find ourselves in the exact same situation.

If you want to be able to pass both instances of `FooClass` and `BarClass`, your best bet is to define the closure as taking `DoThingProtocol`.

For what it's worth, you can *downcast* your closures.  Consider this very simple example:

```
class A {}
class B: A {}

let closureA: (A) -> Void = { arg in
    print(arg)
}

let closureB = closureA as (B) -> Void
```

In this case, `B` is guaranteed to implement everything which `A` has implemented, because `B` inherits from `A`.  There's not necessarily a whole lot of purpose to making this cast though.  The cast only restricts other children class of `A` from being passed in to `closureB`, but as the closure was already implemented as having type `(A) -> Void`, we can't make use of any extra knowledge we'd have about class `B` within the closure.